# Updating the query on the other page and set the button disabled

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a question regarding ajax and modal. What I need to do is, when user click submit of the button, it should set the button disabled and sending the values to the other page to update the database. But my approach is using modal.

My modal code is like this,

```
<div class="modal fade" id="qcRejectModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">QC <font color="CC0000"><b>REJECT</b></font> Confirmation Window</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              This is the confirmation window to PASS all the Quality Control for, <br/><br/>
                              PROJECT : <b>'.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].'</b>
                              HEADMARK : <b>'.$row['HEAD_MARK'].'</b>
                              ID : <b>'.$row['ID'].'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Reason for rejection" rows="2" name="rejectionreason" id="rejectionreason" required></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" name="rejectbutton" id="rejectbutton" class="btn btn-danger">Confirm REJECT!</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

So in this code when user click the button,

```
echo "<input type='hidden' data_project='$row[PROJECT_NAME]' data_headmark='$row[HEAD_MARK]' data_id='$row[ID]'></input>";
echo '<button type="button" name="qcreject" id="qcreject" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger btn- lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#qcRejectModal"> 
                <span style="font-size:35px"> '.$row['PROJECT_NAME'].' / <b>'.$_POST ["hm"].'</b>/'.$row['ID'].' ~ FAIL</span></button>';
```

modal code is executed and showed and waiting for the user to input the comment in the textfield and when user click `REJECT` button, it should pass

`$row['PROJECT_NAME']`, `$row['HEAD_MARK']`, `$row['ID']` and the textfield value (`#rejectionreason`)into the *processclass.php*.

And on the *processclass.php*, those variables will be used to update the database with SQL query.

This is the snippet of my ajax.

```
$('.rejectbutton').click(function() { 

        $.ajax({
            url: 'processclass.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ,
            success: function (result) {
              alert("Your data has been submitted");
            }
        });  

});
```

I am having problem with executing on the process class. that means passing those values to the *processclass.php*.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.rejectbutton').click(function() { 
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'processclass.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {param_name: '<?php echo $param_value ?>'},
            success: function (result) {
              alert("Your data has been submitted");
            },
            complete: function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });  

});
```

Comment: How do I put the data into the data: section in the ajax. That means putting $row[PROJECT_NAME] into the processclass.php.

Comment: I did this and the button does nothing,

`$('.rejectbutton').click(function() { 
                $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'processclass.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            data_project :'<?php echo $row[PROJECT_NAME] ?>',
                            data_headmark :'<?php echo $row[HEAD_MARK] ?>',
                            data_id :'<?php echo $row[ID] ?>'},

Comment: check your console. in network tab you will se what data is being sent and received by the ajax

Comment: I don't see any when I click reject :(

Comment: means your ajax is not fired. put an alert in the first line on click of reject

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54008/discussion-between-chriskonz-and-mohammad-faisal).